# Video Chat going through a server

Tags: video, instant-messaging

I'm trying to build a simple video chat client on the mac as a little project and I want it to be able to go over my own little server and arrive at the other end (so going over the internet rather just locally). So my question is if there are any references I should look for online on how to handle something like this on the server side and such. Any links or pointers would be a great help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your using standard video feeds like a video call, most PBX's will do fine.

One on the cheap is the Asterisk PBX.  Open-source and has a very active community.